# Wi-fi network device has Ethernet link layer

Tags: wifi, network-interface, ethernet

I'm capturing packets using Wireshark on my Macbook.  Pinging some public IP (e.g., 8.8.8.8) shows the ICMP packets going out my `en0` interface.  In Wireshark's capture options, that interface is listed as "Wi-Fi: en0" (which makes sense since I'm connected to my house's Wi-Fi).  However, Wireshark also says that the link layer is Ethernet.  Inspecting the packets confirms this.

Why would a Wi-Fi device be using Ethernet for its link layer?

`ifconfig en0` shows

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 6c:7e:67:ca:42:1e 
    inet6 fe80::c82:675e:647d:ae9d%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xf 
    inet 192.168.1.232 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 2600:4040:248d:4400:10a5:84d1:7da4:b527 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 2600:4040:248d:4400:6452:be0f:3f49:deaa prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you typically transport ethernet packets, typically containing IP packets, over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Perhaps I've got a fundamental misunderstanding regarding the link layer.  I thought that Ethernet and Wi-Fi were two separate link layer types.

Comment: IEEE802.11 specifies the PHY and the MAC layer, everything above is basically pieced together from existing technology

Comment: Isn't Ethernet also a MAC layer?

Comment: yep! That's why you find ethernet addresses in the IEEE802.11 MAC header :)

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting this now.  So, the fact that I'm using Wi-Fi only determines the mechanism by which the packets (in this case, Ethernet) are transmitted from one device to another.  Is that right?

Comment: Cool!  If you could add that to your answer, I'd accept it.